# Peterson's Algorithm to avoid race condition between threads

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, pthreads, pthread-join

### Details:

I am implementing Peterson's Algorithm(below)  to avoid race condition. The way I want to do it, is to declare a global integer variable, and create threads one and two. Whenever the thread one had access to the global variable it should print `a` and add one to the global variable counter. When the thread two have access to this global variable it should print `b` and add one to the global variable counter. This should continue until the global variable reaches a certain number(let's say 10). After that I want the thread(which ever of the two threads that makes the last addition to the global variable) to reset the global variable to 1 and both threads should exit. The code that I have implemented so far kinda does the job,it avoids race condition, but I can't exit both threads when counter reaches limit.

### Question:

- How can I quit both threads when the counter reaches a specific limit.
- Whats the proper form of quitting a thread, right now I am using exit(), which I don't think is very efficient.

### Peterson's Algorithm

```
boolean flag [2];
int turn;
void P0()
{
    while (true) {
         flag [0] = true;
         turn = 1;
         while (flag [1] && turn == 1) /* do nothing */;
         /* critical section */;
         flag [0] = false;
         /* remainder */;
    }
}

void P1()
{
     while (true) {
          flag [1] = true;
          turn = 0;
          while (flag [0] && turn == 0) /* do nothing */;
          /* critical section */;
          flag [1] = false;
          /* remainder */
     }
}

 void main()
 {
       flag [0] = false;
       flag [1] = false;
       parbegin (P0, P1);
 }
```

### My Code:

**EDIT**: I realized that I have to put the if-statement, that is checking for the counter limit value, should be in the critical section(before it changes the flag to false).

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>


int counter = 0;

int flag[2];
int turn;

void *func1(void *);
void *func2(void *);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    pthread_t thread1,thread2;
    //int rt1,rt2;

    flag[0] = 0;
    flag[1] = 0;

    //rt1 = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,&func1,"a");
    //rt2 = pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,&func2,"c");
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,&func1,"a");
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,&func2,"b");

    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

    return 0;
}// End of main function


void *func1(void *message){


    while(1){
        flag[0] = 1;
        turn = 1;
        while(flag[1] && turn == 1);
        printf("%s %d\n",(char *)message,counter);
        counter++;
        flag[0] = 0;        

        if(counter == 10){
            counter = 1;
            printf("exited at func1, with counter %d\n",counter);
            exit(0);
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

void *func2(void *message){

    while(1){
        flag[1] = 1;
        turn = 0;
        while(flag[0] && turn == 0);
        printf("%s %d\n",(char *)message,counter);
        counter++;
        flag[1] = 0;

        if(counter == 10){
            counter = 1;
            printf("exited at func2, with counter %d\n",counter);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a typical example, seen that several times, where an abstract algorithm in the literature is implemented in C without watching for the prerequisites that such algorithms have. The most important here is atomicity of the operations on variables, something that is **not** guaranteed by C nor by POSIX. So what you are trying here can't work like that. Modern C, AKA C11, has atomic datatypes and threads that you could use for that purpose, but usually this is not so easy to aprehend for starters.

Comment: @JensGustedt any advice then on how to implement the algorithm? what to take into consideration?

Comment: Why would you want to implement this algorithm? This is a theoretical algorithm from the literature, a lot of water has passed under the bridges since then. It has no relevance for the tools that you are using. POSIX threads come with their own synchronization tools, use them.

Comment: @JensGustedt its part of an assignment. I should have put that in the question i think,

Comment: I was afraid of that. They should definitively update their courswork. To do that *really* you would have to seek a compiler with C library that implements atomics, very recent gcc and clang should provide that, and start from there.

Comment: @JensGustedt Or you can make your own lock-based atomics and use them. It won't be efficient, but that may not be important.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, implementing such an algorithm with a lock would really be bizarre. The whole goal of this algorithm is to *provide* a lock structure, seemingly out of thin air.

Comment: @JensGustedt It provides a lock structure out of atomic operations. How those atomic operations are implemented doesn't particularly matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, when one thread resets the global counter, the other thread may never see the global counter reaching e.g.10, so it will never quit. What if you simply don't reset the global counter, and let it thread quit whenever it finds the global counter e.g. 10? If you really want to reset the counter, you do that in the parent (main) thread (which is also where you define the global counter).

As for quitting a thread, you can either simply return from the primary thread function (this will end the thread by itself), call `pthread_exit` from within the thread, or you can use `phtread_cancel` from the main function.

Comment: I used return, it simply enters an infinite loop,

Comment: That is because you reset the counter; that's the first paragraph of my answer. If you have that wrong, you can't expect the second part to work properly.

Comment: if i do that, then after executing the threads, it never returns, i have to kill it with ctl+c. But I will try to figure it out,

Comment: Don't test for `counter == 10`, test it for `counter > 9`; one counter may increment it to 10 and the other then to 11 before you get a chance to test the value.